# Best way to override CSS * definition with !important

Tags: html, css

I am working in a product defines its own CSS. Part of their definition is defining all elements like this:

```
* {
  font-face: Helvetica;
  font-size: 12px !important;
}
```

I am creating some screens using their CSS but want to make some changes, like this:

```
.change {
  font-size: 1.25em;
}
```

Now when I have a paragraph inside a div that is assigned the class of change it doesn't work.

```
<div class="change">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
</div>
```

This JSfiddle shows the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/uqogzayn/5/

This JSfiddle shows a wrong working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/uqogzayn/3/

<s>Question: What is the best way to get everything that is inside the div with the class change to use the font size I want?</s>
Question: How to apply my `change` class to everything inside the div while still adhering to CSS best practises?

Comment: `.change * { ... }` ?

Comment: I don't think he's using `!important`, that's what the product that he's using defines..

Comment: Correct. I am not using important. The product's definition is using important and I am including their CSS so my extension pages will blend in.

Comment: To ask for a "best way" is opinion-based. Could you rephrase this question to be more to a point of what you (and your code example reflects this) are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

I continued searching around. First I wanted to see if you could remove a previously made definition. The answer was no. Another option would be to define each sub-element like this:

```
.change p {
  font-size: 1.25em !important;
}
```

While this worked I also know that it is bad CSS form. Also if I have to add an entry for each element that I want to override. And what if there are other classes that I want to create that encounter the same problem.

So I thought about using a reset and came up with:

```
* {
  font-size: inherit !important;
}
body {
  font-size: 12px !important;
}
```

This whole experience made me realize you should never use the wild card selector to declare anything. Everything inside your web page will inherit from body so just define your base in body.

Comment: We could use the wild card selector. Bad practice is using !important keyword. Instead we have to play with the precedence and hierarchy structure of css.

Comment: You can also use wildcards as sub-elements instead of defining each sub-element, i.e. .change * { font-size: 1.25em !important; }

Comment: Yes using !important is bad but I have to use it in this case to override what the original CSS defined since they used important in the * selector.

Answer (score 0):

When you add * it means all elements get this CSS properties and the `<p>` is an element of HTML so it gets the `*` properties not `.change` class you have to add the `.change` class in paragraph like this

```
 <p class="change">
```

or you can add new css class like this

```
.change p
{
font-size:1.25em;
}
```

I hope I have got you right and this is what you want.

Comment: I am trying to avoid explicitly defining `change` for a p tag. That goes against CSS best practices.

Comment: just add new class .change *{ font-size:1.25em; } and it will work

Comment: I don't want to change everything. I just want to change the spot where I apply my class. Besides doing that would be just as bad as the original author's CSS.